# Try to merge git branch and get <<<<<<< HEAD in some files. What does it mean and how can I repair this?

Tags: git

I want to merge a branch to the master. It seems to work mostly, but I get some extra lines in the code and I don't know what they mean

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
some code
=======
some code
>>>>>>> origin/1.1
```

What does it mean and how can I repair this?

Comment: Have you tried to [read the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_how_conflicts_are_presented)? To me you've not attempted to understand this yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are code conflicts that git cannot resolve by itself. You need to choose the code version you want to keep or perhaps both. Just delete the lines (including identifiers added by git) that you don't need.

Try reading about resolving [code conflicts](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/) and git in general. It's more or less part of the first few steps in learning git.

Comment: Thanks for your help